# image fade on hover and show content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

can I get some help here please

I got a code that is working for only one image but cannot for multiple images with different content

HTML

```
<ul id="base">
<li class="element" >
<img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7040/6818412114_261c73da06_z.jpg" class="img1"  />
<div style="display:none;" class="content">this is a text message 2</div>
</li>
<li class="element" >
<img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7040/6818412114_261c73da06_z.jpg" class="img1"  />
<div style="display:none;" class="content">this is a text message 2</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.element {float:left;margin-right:15px;border:1px solid red;width:150px;height:150px;}
.element img {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      height:150px;
      width:150px;
    }
.content {height:150px;width:150px;background:gray;font-size:9px;}
```

jQuery

```
$(".element").hover(function() {
        //fadeout first image using jQuery fadeOut
        $(".img1").fadeOut(300);
        //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
        $(".content").fadeIn(300);
    }, function () {
        //fadeout second image using jQuery fadeOut
        $(".img1").fadeIn(300);
        //fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
        $(".content").fadeOut(300);
    });
```

and a fiddle for testing http://jsfiddle.net/nQvay/1/, need some help

Answer (score 1):

You must specify whose `.img1` and `.content` you want to be faded

```
 $(".element").hover(function() {
            //fadeout first image using jQuery fadeOut
            $(this).children(".img1").fadeOut(300);
            //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
            $(this).children(".content").fadeIn(300);
        }, function () {
            //fadeout second image using jQuery fadeOut
            $(this).children(".img1").fadeIn(300);
            //fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
           $(this).children(".content").fadeOut(300);
        });
```

Comment: hello there, Im not good with this jquery but if you could update the fiddle and would be fine

Comment: hey TaronPro, its working on all browser, even in IE6 but in IE10 the fadein fadeout does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eZUcK/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".element").hover(function() {
            //fadeout first image using jQuery fadeOut
            $(".element").children(".img1").fadeOut(300);
            //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
            $(".element").children(".content").fadeIn(300);
        }, function () {
            //fadeout second image using jQuery fadeOut
           $(".element").children(".img1").fadeIn(300);
            //fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
           $(".element").children(".content").fadeOut(300);
        });
});
```

Comment: both content on boxes appear at the same time, could it be when hover only one box shows that content...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="base">
<li class="element" >
<img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7040/6818412114_261c73da06_z.jpg" class="img1"  />
<div style="display:none;" class="content">this is a text message 2</div>
</li>
<li class="element" >
<img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7040/6818412114_261c73da06_z.jpg" class="img1"  />
<div style="display:none;" class="content">this is a text message 2</div>
</li>
</ul>


<style>
ul{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
list-style:none;
}
.element {float:left;margin-right:15px;border:1px solid red;width:150px;height:150px;position:relative;}
.element img {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      height:150px;
      width:150px;
    }
.content {height:150px;width:150px;background:gray;font-size:9px;}
</style>


<script>
$(".element").hover(function() {
        //fadeout first image using jQuery fadeOut
        $(this).children(".img1").fadeOut(300);
        //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
        $(this).children(".content").fadeIn(300);
    }, function () {
        //fadeout second image using jQuery fadeOut
        $(this).children(".img1").fadeIn(300);
        //fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
        $(this).children(".content").fadeOut(300);
    });
</script>
```